# Can I replace my Shimano Nexus 7 with a Nexus 8 hub?

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, nexus

My 2 year old bike has a (damaged) Nexus 7 IGH, it started running heavy and I can't find out why.

Rather than getting it fixed I'm considering replacing it with a Nexus 8 hub, as they supposedly of higher quality (apart from the obvious extra gear).

Obviously I need a new 8-speed shifter to do this, but it looks to me that I can use the old roller brake assembly and the chain (very little obvious wear).

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Be aware that it may be more cost effective to replace the entire rear wheel rather than replace the hub alone. Spokes generally cannot be re-used and having a wheel re-built with a replacement hub is relatively expensive.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: That was exactly my plan, a complete wheel is only a little more expensive and a lot less work.

Comment: Did you ever give the hub an oil change ?  Could be you're pushing around coal instead of oil inside there.

Comment: I tried oiling the hub earlier this week, but when I put it back in the wheel I could feel the resistance when turning it. I intend to get it to work eventually as a spare, but in the mean time I need a working bike to commute.

Comment: BTW, chains can be worn out but not look worn. Buy a chain wear gauge (they are not expensive) or have a bike shop check it .

Comment: @Pelle I think you're misunderstanding my question - when did you last drain all the liquid oil from inside the hub and refresh it with new liquid oil?  An IGH is an oil-bath gearbox just like a car so it runs in liquid oil.  I am not referring to squirting oil on the outside.

Comment: @criggy No, I did the whole oil bath thing, but that was the first time after more than 2 years of daily use. So I'm afraid it was too little too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what roller brake model you have.

Looking at the [Shimano 2015-1026 component line up document](http://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2015-2016_Line-up_chart_v024_en.pdf) you can see what components work together. (Very useful current line up web pages [here](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/2.3), with links to PDF docs for previous years.)

You presumably have a Nexus SG-C3000-7R hub. That should be paired with the BR-IM81-R, BR-C6000-R, BR-C3010-R or BR-C3000-R roller brakes.

The Nexus 8 is the SG-C6000-8R or SG-C6010-8R hub which works with the BR-IM81-R
or BR-C6000-R brakes only.

The PDF doc is very long, but you can search for the product numbers to find the Nexus 7 and 8 sections.

Comment: That looks like a fun puzzle to solve, I'll have a look at my parts and what I can buy as an upgrade

Comment: Yes, it is a SG-C3000-7R, and unfortunately paired with the BR-C3000-R. I may try to use the brake anyway, as the more expensive sets fit both hubs, so the mounting should be compatible (I think). I can always upgrade both brakes to a better series later.

Comment: @Pelle, yeah, definitely worth a try

Comment: I have just completed the replacement by a SG-6001-8R, the roller brake fit just fine. Now to find out if it is the improvement I hope it would be.